# Split HTML nested list into python list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I have HTML list formed that way (It's what CKeditor create for nested list):

```
<ul>
    <li>niv1alone</li>
    <li>niv1
        <ul>
            <li>niv2
                <ul>
                    <li>niv3
                        <ul>
                            <li>niv4</li>
                            </ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>
    <li>autre niv1 alone</li>
</ul>
```

How do I form a "recursive list" like that:

```
[
    ('niv1alone',[]),('niv1',[('niv2',[('niv3',[('niv4',[])])])]),('autre niv1 alone',[])
]
```

I have tried several things with `beautifulsoup` but I can't get the desired result.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive function that functions similar to what you ask. Trick to writing recursive functions is to make the problem smaller then recurse it. Here I'm walking down the element tree and passing the children, which is a strictly smaller set than one before.

```py
import bs4

html = '''
<ul>
    <li>niv1alone</li>
    <li>niv1
        <ul>
            <li>niv2
                <ul>
                    <li>niv3
                        <ul>
                            <li>niv4</li>
                            </ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>
    <li>autre niv1 alone</li>
</ul>
'''


def make_tree(body: bs4.Tag):
    branch = []
    for ch in body.children:
        if isinstance(ch, bs4.NavigableString):
            # skip whitespace
            if str(ch).strip():
                branch.append(str(ch).strip())
        else:
            branch.append(make_tree(ch))
    return branch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tree = make_tree(soup.select_one('ul'))
    print(tree)
```

output:

```
[['niv1alone'], ['niv1', [['niv2', [['niv3', [['niv4']]]]]]], ['autre niv1 alone']]
```

Comment: Thanks that exactly what i needed and with explanation to understand it it's PERFECTION :D
Huge thanks man :)